# $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x \implies f$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x$ then does it imply $f$ is uniformly continuous?

My idea is suppose I want to calculate $f(10)$ then what i basically do is that $f(10)=f(9)=f(8) = \cdots = f(1)= f(0)$.

I am planning to restrict the domain to a compact set so that it because uniformly conintuous automatically. Is my idea correct?

A formal solution will help.
Thanks

Comment: Exactly. By restricting f to the Interval [0,1], you can show that it is uniformly continuous everywhere.

Comment: @Mathematician : So all periodic functions are constant?

Comment: Without doing the problem myself: your plan should work. Restrict it to [0,2] and get a u.c. function, then the $\delta$ you get from that should work on the whole real line.

Comment: It is true if one restrict $f$ to $[0,1]$, one can still show $f$ uniform continuous everywhere. However, this will need some special handling at the end points (e.g. what if one want to show the value of $f$ at $2.999$ is close to that at $3.001$ ). Instead, one can simplify the proof by using a slightly bigger interval $[-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove $\forall \delta>0, \exists \varepsilon>0, \forall x, y \in \Bbb R, \left[\left|y-x\right| \le \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|f(y)-f(x)\right|<\delta\right]$

---

Let $\delta>0$

By the Heine–Cantor theorem on $\left[-2,2\right]$, $\exists \varepsilon>0,\forall a,b \in \left[-2,2\right], \left[\left|b-a\right| \le \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|f\left(b\right)-f\left(a\right)\right|<\delta\right]$

Let $ x,y\in \Bbb R$

$\exists (q_x,r_x) \in \Bbb Z\times [0.1), x = q_x+r_x$

$\exists (q_y,r_y) \in \Bbb Z\times [0.1), y = q_y+r_x+r_y$

With $a=r_x,b=r_x+r_y$, $\left[\left|\left(r_y+r_x\right)-r_x\right| \le \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|f\left(r_y+r_x\right)-f\left(r_x\right)\right|<\delta\right]$

We have that $\left|r_y\right|= \left|\left(r_x+r_y\right)-r_x\right|=\left|\left(y-q_y\right)-\left(x-q_x\right)\right|\le\left|y-x\right|+\left|q_y-q_x\right| \le \left|y-x\right|$

So $\left|y-x\right| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|r_y\right| < \varepsilon$

So $\left|y-x\right| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow\left|\left(r_y+r_x\right)-r_x\right| \le \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|f\left(r_y+r_x\right)-f\left(r_x\right)\right|<\delta$

So $\left|y-x\right| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|f\left(r_y+r_x\right)-f\left(r_x\right)\right|<\delta$

Since we also have $f\left(x\right)=f\left(q_x+r_x\right)=f\left(r_x\right)$

and $f\left(y\right)=f\left(q_y+r_y+r_x\right)=f\left(r_y+r_x\right)$

We can conclude that $\left|y-x\right| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|f\left(y\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|<\delta$